# Upgrading to the new Admob issues

Tags: android, admob

First, I have put this into my manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Then, inside each layout I want my ads to appear in, I have put this in its `.xml` up

```
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and this down

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-abb-psb-4557896546544844/5789887777"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and at last, I have imported the library `google-play-services_libs`

The problem now that I get `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 'aaa.bbb.ccc'` from the `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView .... >` in the xml.

And I get `R cannot be resolved to a variable` in all of my app classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView#xml-attributes

`LoadOnCreate` cannot be used anymore as XML attribute.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

---

```
// Java code required.
// testDevices and loadAdOnCreate attributes are
// no longer available.
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Note that the link in the answer is less useful than it was, because Google is redirecting to Firebase AdMob documentation.

Comment: @dpjanes Thanks for pointing that out. Link has been removed.